# Returning queryfetch and output specific row

Tags: php, mysql

What i wish to do:
Return a queryfetch from a function, and output the content from a specific tablerow, depending on its "name".

```
The database:
Rownames     Input1     Input2
id           1          2
name         defense    attack
value        10         15
```

The function i'm using at the moment is this:

```
public function stat_query($stat_name, $user_id = null) 
{
$core = db_core::getInstance();
$query = $core->conn->query("SELECT user_stats.value as value FROM user_stats INNER JOIN stats ON user_stats.stat_id = stats.id WHERE user_stats.user_id = ".$this->get_user($user_id) AND stats.name = '".$stat_name."'");
$value = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
return $value;
}
```

Now with the function above, i would have to query the database everytime i needed a stat. But i wish to query the database once and store it, so that i can call a specific stat lateron.

Say i want to output defense; I'd output $storedquery['defense'] and same goes for attack.
What is the best way to do this?

Comment: I think you are looking for fetchAll (http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php)? Alternatively, if you're looking for storage, you could store values in the session. ($_SESSION)

Comment: agree with RobotRock. If you want to store anything in your application for using later and you are not using cache. Try SESSION's.

Comment: Just to clarify; Would the best way be to store the data in a session array?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use it multiple times within the same execution, create a global variable, set it to false.

Then change the function to be:

```
public function stat_query($stat_name, $user_id = null) 
{
   if($yourGlobalVar){
      return $yourGlobalVar;
   else{
      $core = db_core::getInstance();
      $query = $core->conn->query("SELECT user_stats.value as value FROM user_stats INNER JOIN stats ON user_stats.stat_id = stats.id WHERE user_stats.user_id = ".$this->get_user($user_id) AND stats.name = '".$stat_name."'");
      $value = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
      return $value;
   }
}
```

If you want to save it for the duration of a session, use the SESSION. Do you need assistance with using SESSION?